# cuando hago click en el icono de hamburguesa me sale error

Tags: javascript, menu, sidebar

tengo estos trozos de codigo:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="top_navbar">
        <div class="hamburger">
            <a href="#"">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>         
</div

var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("active");
});
```

y me muestra este error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

la variable hamburger en la consola me sale null ....
estoy usando el "includeHTML.js" para dividir por trozos mi archivo html

Comment: Sospecho que el problema viene por el momento en el que llamas al código. Si este código Javascript lo pones en el head tal y como está, se ejecutará antes de que se cargue el DOM y por lo tanto el div hamburguer aún no existirá. Prueba a poner el script al final de la página o a cargarlo en el evento onload del body

Comment: Podrías cerrar correctamente el `div` más exterior y reintentar.